# PyTorch Lightning DDP Error with SLURM: GPU MisconfigurationException and Devices Mismatch

Tags: gpu, torch, slurm, lightning

I'm running a PyTorch Lightning training script on a SLURM-managed cluster using Distributed Data Parallel (DDP). My setup involves 1 node with 4 GPUs. However, I'm encountering issues with the configuration of GPUs in my training script.

**Environment:**

- PyTorch Lightning
- SLURM cluster with 1 node and 4 GPUs

**Trainer Configuration in YAML:**

```yaml
trainer:
  _target_: lightning.pytorch.trainer.Trainer
  default_root_dir: ${paths.run_dir}
  # ... other settings ...
  accelerator: gpu
  devices: 4
  strategy: ddp
```

**SBATCH Script:**

```bash
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --partition=gpu
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:4
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=4
#SBATCH --output=/project/home/<project>/output/output.txt
#SBATCH --error=/project/home/<project>/output/error.txt

# set python path to poetry environent in home

cd repos/myrepo
srun python -m myrepo.main
```

**Issue:**

1. When I set `devices: 4` in the Trainer configuration, I receive the following error four times:

   ```
   Error in call to target 'lightning.pytorch.trainer.trainer.Trainer':
   MisconfigurationException('You requested gpu: [0, 1, 2, 3]\n But your machine only has: [0]')
   ```
2. If I change the `devices` to `-1`, I get this error:

   ```
   ValueError: You set `devices=1` in Lightning, but the number of tasks per node configured in SLURM `--ntasks-per-node=4` does not match. HINT: Set `devices=4`.
   ```
3. If I replace `srun python` by `python`, then it works. However, lightning clearly recommends using srun in their docs, and I get this warning:

   ```
   The `srun` command is available on your system but is not used. HINT: If your intention is to run Lightning on SLURM, prepend your python command with `srun` like so: srun python .../repos/myrepo
   ```

It seems like there's a mismatch or misconfiguration in how the GPUs are being requested or recognized between PyTorch Lightning and SLURM.

**Questions:**

1. How should I correctly configure the GPU devices in PyTorch Lightning's Trainer to work with SLURM's DDP setup?
2. What's the difference between `srun python` and `python` within the sbatch script?

Any insights or suggestions on resolving these errors would be greatly appreciated.